# Elasticsearch sort by terms values' order

Tags: elasticsearch, microservices, software-design

I'm connecting my recommendation service with product service. The recommendation service, no matter what the parameters are, always returns a list of product ID sorted by relevancy. Example:

```
["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]
```

The product service owns Elasticsearch indices that store the details of the products. The client expects the data of the recommended products along with the product details ordered by the relevancy. Hence I'm using this search query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {
          "terms": {
            "product_id": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the result from that query is not sorted by the terms values' order. What changes can I make to achieve the goals?

P.S.: Any advice or reference in Elasticsearch index design, services' response format, or the system design for recommendation system would be much welcomed.

Comment: on what basis do you want the result to be sorted ?

Comment: The basis is determined by the ML in recommendation service, might be based on a similar product or even time of the day. The product service (ES indices) shouldn't know about the sort basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `terms` query functions as an `OR` filter that scores the matches in a bool manner (`true -> 1`, `false -> 0`).

Having said that, you could generate a similar `OR` query via a `query_string` query that'd [boost the individual IDs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boosting), thus increase their score, and consequently sort them higher:

```json
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "product_id",
            "query": "ID1^3 OR ID2^2 OR ID3^1"
          }
        }
      ], 
      "filter":[
        {
          "terms": {
            "product_id": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The boost values above can of course be dynamically changed to account for the varying length of the list of IDs.

Comment: I also find out that to avoid filter terms besides the query_string, I can apply min_score: 0.1